# Identifying an unknown coordinate system

Tags: geoprocessing, coordinate-system

I'm currently doing some software work on a set of exports of a maritime database. But I have no idea how to approach this, as I do not know the coordinate system in use. I am hoping that it is a known (although somewhat obscure) system, and not something homebrewed.

Here's an extract:

```
4111.099998 898.500000
4110.559998 899.800002
4111.240002 902.910000
4111.840002 901.500000
```

I have reason to believe that these correspond to:

```
68.5306667N, 15.0250000E
68.5183333N, 14.9750000E
68.5206667N, 15.0485000E
68.5306667N, 15.0250000E
```

(somewhere in the Norwegian or Barents Sea)

Anyone able to identfy the system, so that I can work with these coordinates?

Comment: Approach the custodian of the data and ask them, look at any metadata statements you may have received.. it could be time/depth information on the path of a ship which you would need some sort of tracklog to align from but that's just a stab in the dark.

Comment: One possibility is that the values are in kilometers and/or listed as northing, easting, but I'm not finding a known projected CRS that matches either way.

Comment: I was thinking Something like Northing/Easting in metric, but with an unusual origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is far simpler than I first thought: A friend of mine noticed that the coordinates are regular lat/lon decimal degrees, but multiplied by 60.

In other words, decimal minutes, as per the comment below.

Comment: Oh, so the data's in decimal minutes. Thank you very much for answering!